# cross-platform openGLES?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, cross-platform

Is there a best/good way to go about cross-platform app development, like a game, for Android and iOS simultaneously (and Mac OS X)?

Just to simply develop an app that uses OpenGL and C/C++ only should be very simple, shouldn't it?  As long as I didn't get into sound or even interaction at first?

I looked into the NDK, but there are all these warnings about how people shouldn't use it.  I want to do everything myself as much as possible so I have not looked into things like Cocos2D ... is there any tutorial which just gets like an openGL "Hello World" going cross platform?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: if you want to reuse code you cannot use C++, only C

Answer (score 2):

Unity3d (game engine) is the best and easiest way to develop cross platform games. Due to the facts thats is supports many platforms.

The Platforms supported by unity3d are Android, Iphone, Mac & Window, web, Flash, Ps3, Wii, and even Linux. 
The main benefit of using it is you do not have to rewrite your code (only some minor changes) to port it other platforms.

It supports C#, Javascript as well as boo for scripting.
The best thing about it. It has a strong support and great community to solve your problems.

You can create a cross platform Hello World in Unity3d in few minutes for various platforms like mac, windows, android, iphone, web.

I know it is not close (unity3d) as you want to pure coding enviroment but if your objective is cross platform games then unity3d is the best way (also the fastest).

Check it out http://unity3d.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing a multi-platform game (iOS,Android,Java-openGL,Flash and HTML5) using a google framework called PlayN http://code.google.com/p/playn/
It works great and have had a good feedback from the author when I hit problems